Swiper slides not always pressed to the left edge with loop and auto slidesPerView
I've a problem with SwiperJS core. When I'm dragging with random long swipes, sometimes leftmost slide not always pressed to the left edge of swiper container.
Here is a small reproduction based on one of swiper demos: reproduction
Screenshots with normal and abnormal slides state below:
normal slides position

 normal slides position

abnormal slides position

 abnormal slides position

Looks like sometimes Swiper aligns slides to the right
I've already tried "slidesPerGroup: 1", "longSwipes: false" options.
Update:
SOLVED
Just added touchRatio: 0.1 to disable scrolling multiple slides by 1 drag
